# Error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SaveAs' Conviertiendo a docx a pdf, en aplicación Django desplegada con wsgi Apache en windows

Tags: django, apache, pdf

En un aplicación hecha con Django y desplegada con WSGI en Apache en Windows, tengo una función que convierte un archivo docx a pdf y me da el error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SaveAs'.
La función funciona perfectamente en el servidor de desarrollo de Django, pero con Apache da el error mencionado.
Parece que no encuentra Microsoft Word y no abre el archivo. No se si tendrá algo que ver con pywin32. Las direcciones de los archivos devuelven datos correctos.
He probado a modificar la función utilizado la librería docx2pdf y da el mismo error.
He añadido en variables del entorno del sistema en el path C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16
También he probado a poner en el archivo de configuración de Apache SetEnv PATH "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Office/root/Office16;%PATH%" """ Código  def convertir_a_pdf(request, id):

```
paciente = get_object_or_404(Paciente, pk=id)
firma_lopd = FirmaLopd.objects.get(paciente_id=paciente)

if firma_lopd.documento_lopd_pdf and os.path.isfile(firma_lopd.documento_lopd_pdf.path):
    os.remove(firma_lopd.documento_lopd_pdf.path)

# Obtener la ruta del archivo de Word
word_file = firma_lopd.documento_lopd.path

# Definir el nombre del archivo PDF
pdf_filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(word_file))[0] + ".pdf"

# Crear la ruta relativa del archivo PDF a partir de la ruta de subida en el modelo
pdf_path = os.path.relpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(word_file), pdf_filename), settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

# Inicializar la API COM
pythoncom.CoInitialize()

# Inicializar la aplicación Word de Windows
word_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

# Abrir el archivo de Word
doc = word_app.Documents.Open(word_file)

# Guardar el archivo de Word como PDF
doc.SaveAs(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, pdf_path), FileFormat=17)

# Cerrar el archivo de Word y la aplicación Word de Windows
doc.Close()
word_app.Quit()

# Asignar la ruta relativa del archivo PDF al campo "documento_lopd_pdf" del objeto "firma_lopd"
firma_lopd.documento_lopd_pdf = pdf_path

# Guardar los cambios en el objeto "firma_lopd"
firma_lopd.save()

pythoncom.CoUninitialize()

return redirect('pestanyaspacientes', id=paciente.id)"""
```